# dynamically update RecyclerView on SqLite database dataset change

Tags: android, database, sqlite, android-recyclerview, notifydatasetchanged

I have a fairly simple implementation of a high score leader board here that saves the name provided by the user alongside his or her score. 
Unfortunately, upon returning to the high score activity the RecyclerView will only show the score that had previously been populated, not the new one that was just entered. I am using notifyDatasetChanged() method in an async task. Still no success. Any pointers are much appreciated.

The high score activity:

```
public class HighscoreActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener{

SQLiteDatabase db;
ArrayList<String> nameList;
ArrayList<String> scoreList;
RecyclerView recyclerView;
ScoreRecViewAdapter scoreRecViewAdapter;
Button buttonStart;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_highscore);

    buttonStart = findViewById(R.id.buttonStart);
    buttonStart.setOnClickListener(this);

    // create lists and table
    nameList = new ArrayList<>();
    scoreList = new ArrayList<>();
    db = this.openOrCreateDatabase("Scores", MODE_PRIVATE, null);
    db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS scores(name VARCHAR, score VARCHAR)");

    //Cursor c = db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM scores", null);
    Cursor c = db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM scores ORDER BY score DESC", null);

    // Fill list
    int nameIndex = c.getColumnIndex("name");
    int scoreIndex = c.getColumnIndex("score");

    while ( c.moveToNext() ){
        nameList.add(c.getString(nameIndex));
        scoreList.add(c.getString(scoreIndex));
    }

    // put data in rec view
    recyclerView = findViewById(R.id.recView);
    scoreRecViewAdapter = new ScoreRecViewAdapter(this, nameList, scoreList);
    recyclerView.setAdapter(scoreRecViewAdapter);
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));

    // enter new user data
    Intent getter = getIntent();
    String nameExtra = getter.getStringExtra("name");
    String scoreExtra = getter.getStringExtra("score");

    if( nameExtra != null && scoreExtra != null) {
        // perform async task
        new InsertIntoDatabase().execute(nameExtra, scoreExtra);
    }
}

@Override
public void onClick(View view) {
    if (view.getId() == R.id.buttonStart) {
        Intent actorQuizz = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
        startActivity(actorQuizz);
    }
}

public class InsertIntoDatabase extends AsyncTask<String, Integer, String> {

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... strings) {
        db.execSQL("INSERT INTO scores (name, score) VALUES ('" + strings[0] + "', '" + strings[1] +"')");
        Log.i("score saved", "success");
        return "success";
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String s) {
        //nameList.clear();
        //scoreList.clear();

        Cursor c = db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM scores", null);

        // Fill list
        int nameIndex = c.getColumnIndex("name");
        int scoreIndex = c.getColumnIndex("score");

        while ( c.moveToNext() ){
            nameList.add(c.getString(nameIndex));
            scoreList.add(c.getString(scoreIndex));
        }

        scoreRecViewAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
}
```

}

and the recyclerview adapter:

public class ScoreRecViewAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter {

```
Context mContext;
ArrayList<String> nameList;
ArrayList<String> scoreList;

public ScoreRecViewAdapter (Context context, ArrayList<String> nameList, ArrayList<String> scoreList) {
    this.mContext = context;
    this.nameList = nameList;
    this.scoreList = scoreList;
}


@NonNull
@Override
public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View v = LayoutInflater.from(mContext).inflate(R.layout.rec_menu,parent, false);
    return new ViewHolder(v);
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull ViewHolder holder, int position) {
    holder.nameView.setText(nameList.get(position));
    holder.scoreView.setText(scoreList.get(position));
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return nameList.size();
}

public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    TextView nameView;
    TextView scoreView;

    public ViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        nameView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.textViewName);
        scoreView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.textViewScore);
    }
}
}
```